# Does ITextRenderer support font awesome

Tags: font-awesome, html-to-pdf

I am try to render an pdf from html free marker template, I use font awesome fonts, but when I try to render in pdf, the font is not shown, does itextrenderer support such custom font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggled with this as well, but I figured out that I have to add the font manually to get it working. Here's my code:

```
def html2Pdf(html: String): Array[Byte] = {
    val output: ByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream

    val renderer: ITextRenderer = new ITextRenderer()
    renderer.getFontResolver.addFont("fontawesome-webfont.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true)

    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html)
    renderer.layout()
    renderer.createPDF(output)
    renderer.finishPDF()
    output.flush()
    output.close()

    output.toByteArray
}
```

Comment: It's not working for me. The font-awesome icons doesn't render.